# Magento connected to git

Tags: cms-block, git

I installed magento on my ubuntu local machine, and I connected that to github, when I make changes to the magento CMS for example, on my local machine I changed the content of the home page, I expected to see the differences by running a git status, but no differences shows up, and when I push the magento to git, still the changes I have made don't show up. At the beginning I initialized the git and I have added the entire content of the directory to the repository, there's no git ignore files or any missing files. 
What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "when I make changes to the magento CMS for example" you mean you are changing your cms blocks through the admin interface? or you are making changes to php/phtml files?

If you are doing changes on your cms blocks using the admin interface then you wont see your changes in git since those changes go to your DB, more precisely to cms_block table.

If you would like to migrate your content from your local to a testing/production server take a look to this tool:

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/firegento-contentsync

Comment: Thanks for the reply, That is exactly the case, I changed the cms through the admin interface, and then I found that cms_block table on the localhost database indeed changed. But as you said there is no connection between the database and the git. I am now gonna take a look at the tool.

Comment: yes, I usually do this changes with upgrade scripts in magento, this way you are able to track your changes in git and also your data is always consistent. Check this: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/. If this helped you please accept the answer

Comment: I read the article you sent me, to get this clear, you have written your own extension module with the 4 installation, installation upgrade, data script and data upgrade, to apply and track changes in git? But you need to write the 4 scripts in order to do this?